# How to get all childs of a particular node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I **have this relationship in my neo4j**:

```
Parent -> Childs
F -> D,E
D -> A,B,C
```

**Use case**: I am trying to get all child of a particular node using this query

```
MATCH (p:Person{name:"F"})<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(c) 
RETURN {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}}
```

This returns me this :

```
{"parent":"F","child":{"name":["D","A","B","C","E"]}}
```

`A, B, C` are not direct child of F as they are child of `D`

**Required response is**

```
[
"F" : [ Childs i.e "E", "D" ]
"E" : []
"D" : [ "A", "B", "C" ]
 and so on ....
]
```

One way to achieve this is fire this below query recursively :

```
MATCH (p:Person{name:"F"})<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(c) 
RETURN {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}}
```

Which returns

```
{"parent":"F","child":{"name":["E","D"]}}
```

Then search for all childs of `E and D` and then childs of childs and so on..

My question is can I achieve this in a single query or in a more better way?

**Edit1** : Adding dataset

```
CREATE (f:Person {name: "F"})
CREATE (e:Person {name: "E"})
CREATE (d:Person {name: "D"})
CREATE (c:Person {name: "C"})
CREATE (b:Person {name: "B"})
CREATE (a:Person {name: "A"})
CREATE (x:Person {name: "X"})
CREATE (a)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(x)
CREATE (d)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(a)
CREATE (d)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(b)
CREATE (d)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(c)
CREATE (f)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(d)
CREATE (f)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(e)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [OPTIONAL MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/optional-match/#query-optional-match) to achieve your goal.

Your data set looks like this:

[image: Data set]

Try it:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(c) 
RETURN {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}}
```

Query results:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}} |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| {parent=D, child={name=[C, B, A]}}                  |
| {parent=A, child={name=[]}}                         |
| {parent=C, child={name=[]}}                         |
| {parent=F, child={name=[E, D]}}                     |
| {parent=E, child={name=[]}}                         |
| {parent=B, child={name=[]}}                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

In case you need only a specific parent and yours respective children you can do:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = "D"
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(c) 
WITH COLLECT (c) + p AS all
UNWIND all as p
MATCH (p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(c) 
RETURN {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}}
```

As result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}} |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| {parent=D, child={name=[C, B, A]}}                  |
| {parent=A, child={name=[]}}                         |
| {parent=C, child={name=[]}}                         |
| {parent=B, child={name=[]}}                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

From the comment by @Prakash Pandey:

> how can we do something like childs, childs of childs and so on where
>   p.name = "Tom"

Based on the data set added in the question, you can do:

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(c:Person)
WHERE p.name = "X"
WITH COLLECT (c) + p AS all UNWIND all as p
MATCH (p)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(c)
RETURN {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}}
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}} |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| {parent=D, child={name=[F]}}                        |
| {parent=A, child={name=[D]}}                        |
| {parent=X, child={name=[A]}}                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: this search for entire graph, how can we do something like childs, childs of childs and so on where p.name = "Tom"

Comment: Bruno could you please varify , I tried ur query 

`MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = "X"
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(c) 
WITH COLLECT (c) + p AS all
UNWIND all as p
MATCH (p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-(c) 
RETURN {parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}}`


which is returning me nodes up to only 2 levels

`"{parent : p.name, child : {name :collect( c.name)}}"
{"parent":"A","child":{"name":["D"]}}
{"parent":"X","child":{"name":["A"]}}
`

I have added my queries using which I am inserting data so that you wont have to write. Please have a look at it

Comment: Note I have added query in edit section of my question, using which I am inserting data , when using ur query as stated above , its only returning me child upto 2 level

Comment: It should ideally return 
`X->A, A->D, D->F`

Comment: but it only returning to `X->A, A->D and not D->F`

Comment: Hello @PrakashPandey. I edited my answer! :) Take a look!

Comment: Many, Many thanks, seems it worked for bottom up traversing, thought will test it on Top_Down_Treversing. Many thanks again

Comment: @Brunu can their is a way in which I can get this JSON format directly , otherwise I will have to compute it on Java, which will take more processing time.

`{  
   "F":{  
      "metadata":{  
         "name":"Rahul"
      },
      "childs":[  
         "id#1",
         "id#2"
      ]
   }
}`

Comment: `F` is a node, childs are its child like above and `metadata` is more properties that is present at node

Comment: Are `id#1` and `id#2` direct children from F?

Comment: Yes they are direct children's of f

Comment: I think that the main problem of this return format is the fact that you need a dynamic key (In your example "F"). for example, if your query by "D" this key will be "D". I do not know if is possible make it with Cypher. Maybe exists some APOC function to help you with this, but I do not know. I suggest you to change your format to `RETURN {parent : p.name, metadata : {name : p.name}, children : collect( "id#" + ID(c) ) }`.

Comment: Remeber that is not a good idea relying in Neo4j internal IDs because these IDs are [reused internally by Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#match-node-by-id). If this answer solved your problem remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it for informs others that your issue is resolved and to help future viewers of your question

Comment: `id#1` and `id#2`  are just like any metadata property of a node like name, age, Id

Answer (score 3):

I created the graph you describe.

The following query returns most of what you need:

```
MATCH (a:Parent)<-[r:isParent*0..]-(b:Parent)
return {parent:a.name,child : {name :collect( b.name)}}
```

Result:

> {"parent":"D","child":{"name":["D","A","B","C"]}}
>
> {"parent":"A","child":{"name":["A"]}}
>
> {"parent":"C","child":{"name":["C"]}}
>
> {"parent":"F","child":{"name":["F","D","E","A","B","C"]}}
>
> {"parent":"E","child":{"name":["E"]}}
>
> {"parent":"B","child":{"name":["B"]}}